# Hibernate Search with Lucene

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have implemented a custom `ClassBridge` that implements `StringBridge`.

```
public class AClassBridge implements StringBridge {

public String objectToString(Object object) {
   ....
}
```

---

```
@Entity
.....
@ClassBridge(
            name="allTitles",
            index=Index.YES,
            store=Store.NO,
            impl=AClassBridge.class),
private class .... {
....
```

When I index my entites this Bridge is called which is expected but when I search using the  field name associated with this ClassBridge in my lucene search query.

```
"bq.add(new 
BooleanClause(qb.keyword().onFields("allTitles").matching(searchText).createQuery(), 
BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));".
```

The class `Bridge` is called again.

Is this correct behavior when implementing the `org.hibernate.search.bridge.StringBridge`,
or should the Bridge only be called when indexing.

Thanking you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected, the *matching()* method expects you to pass the Object, not the String, and it will attempt to convert the parameter to a String using the defined bridges.

You can disable it using *ignoreFieldBridge()*, which suggests you want to pass the text directly.